# Using Imagemagick, how do I crop out the white background?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Let's say I have a directory full of flags (200 or so). Each flag has this border... 12px up and down and 1px left and rigtht.... like so:

[image]

How can I use imagemagick to like... crop every single .PNG image from 64x64 to 60x40

Comment: Note that your background is not white, but transparent, in the image included in the question.

Comment: Huh.. ah I see... transparent background -- thank you.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly || PHP custom color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567816/trimming-images-with-imagick || http://superuser.com/questions/654557/how-to-auto-trim-scanned-images-using-imagemagick-or-graphicsmagick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the automatic crop: `mogrify -trim flag.png`. If it does not do the exact magic you want, use crop: `mogrify -crop 60x40+2+12 flag.png` (That is *2* pixels left).

Comment: Note: `mogrify` is the in-place version of `convert`.

Comment: `-fuzz N%` can also help with `-trim` in case the back ground color isn't exactly all one collor.