# Trimming extra white background from image using ImageMagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a series of images that I am converting to thumbnails using PHP ImageMagick.  The images are JPEG files of products on plain white backgrounds.  The white space around the images are uneven so I want to trim away the extra background.  Here is what I have tried:

```
$im = new Imagick($imgurl);
$im->trimImage(0);
$im->thumbnailImage(200,0);
$im->writeImage("thumb/".$imgurl);
```

This works as far as the `thumbnailImage()` is concerned creating a thumbnail that is 200 px wide, but the `trimImage()` does not have any effect leaving me with the same amount of surrounding whitespace as in the original image.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong or how else I might achieve this.  I understand that `imagemagick` `trimImage()` can use fuzz, but I couldn't find a good example of how this should be used.

Here is a sample image:

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: Read this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567816/trimming-images-with-imagick

Comment: @bodi0 I found this question and tried several of the suggested workarounds but no luck.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I have updated my question and added a sample image.

Comment: No PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098965/using-imagemagick-how-do-i-crop-out-the-white-background

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some `fuzz` into your `trimImage()`

I did a really quick experiment, that worked:

```
$im->trimImage(20000);
```

It seems around 2,000 is enough for this image. It is relative to the Quantum Range which is 65,536 if your ImageMagick is compiled with `Q16`. Try running:

```
identify | head -1
```

to see your Quantum Size, like this:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-04
```

If you want to get the Quantum Range in your PHP code, use this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getquantumrange.php), then you can express it as a percentage in case you ever use a Q8 or Q32 version of ImageMagick.

If you want to experiment at the Terminal/Command-line, the equivalent command is to set the `fuzz` before running `trim`, so the following is the equivalent of `$im->trimImage(6553);`

```
convert bike.jpg -fuzz 10% -trim out.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried changing the trim image value, but obviously I didn't set it nearly high enough to work.

Comment: I made the same mistake, but I have learned to bash these things really hard till I know what they are doing, then back off if necessary! Good luck!